# Bootstrap dropdown positioning on a scrollable container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Opening a dropdown will occupy a space that will show the vertical scrollbar of the parent container. Trying to add a `overflow-y: hidden` will crop the dropdown. How can I make the dropdown float above the scrollable container relatively?

`See in` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eup0dfj1/)

Comment: why cant you try overflow-x: hidden for scrollable-container?

Comment: Adding an overflow-x:hidden will hide and cropped the dropdown causing for me not to click any of the options @charankumar

Comment: oh, in your fiddle, i can be able to click, so added a comment to hide overflow-x

Comment: Oh yes. I mean I need the overflow-x but not the overflow-y. If you tried to add overflow-y:hidden with absolute position it will crop the dropdown. Since the dropdown not is set to `fixed` overflow will not affect.

Comment: so what you exactly want ? the dropdown should be scrollable?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eup0dfj1/, what I want is for the dropdown not to occupy a vertical space which is the y-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this:

```
.dropdown-menu { 
    position: relative !important;
 ...
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it will also occupy a space vertical. I also tried an absolute positioning but it will also occupy a vertical space.